# How to remove brackets and quotation marks from JSON String

Tags: android, json, string

I have a ArrayAdapter the places JSON strings into a list view. The problem is when it places the strings into the textview it leaves brackets and quotation marks. For example, if the string contained the name Bob. The string would show up in the ListView as ["Bob"]. How do I remove the brackets and quotation marks?

Here is what I use to get the JSON strings,

```
String username = json2.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
String number = json2.getString(KEY_NUMBER);
String content = json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT);
tempList2.add (new Item (username, number, content));
customAdapter.addAll(tempList2);
```

Comment: How does your `customAdapter` bind each `Item` to a `View`? What's in `getView` (or `bindView` if you're using a `CursorAdapter`)? It seems like it's doing some kind of `toString`/serialization on your items before binding it to the item view's `TextView`.

Comment: Well I did what phil told me to do and it worked. So it was defiantly because of the JSON.

Comment: Phil's solution simply patches the consequences but does not address the origin of the problem. It's hard for us to tell where the error is, as you never posted the original input JSON. It could be that the value associated with `KEY_USERNAME` is an *array* containing the string `"Bob"`, which would be parsed as a `JSONArray` containing one `String`. In that case, `getString` would call `toString` on a `JSONArray` which returns a JSON representation of that `JSONArray`. That could explain the brackets, but there's no way to be sure without having the input JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `replace`:

```
String bob = "[\"Bob\"]";
bob = bob.replace("[", "").replace("\"", "").replace("]", "");

Log.i("Test", bob);
```

This will now just print `Bob`

Comment: For replacing the quotes, use .replaceAll("\"", "") instead of .replace(). .replace() will only affect the first instance it comes across. So the above code would print Bob".

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to Phil's answer, the end quote (in my chrome browser) did not get removed. I fixed it by using `.replace("\"", "")` again at the end.